# GLEW (OpenGL Extension Wrangler): Loading opengl dll at runtime?

Tags: glew

I would like to load `opengl32.dll` at **runtime** (using `LoadLibrary` from Win32) and then load OpenGL2/3/4 functions. I tried to use glew for that, but it can't resolve some wgl functions.

**So** is there an easy way I can use glew to import OpenGL functionalities **while** loading opengl dynamically ?

Comment: You should show your code. When you say "can't resolve" I am assuming your compilation is failing?

Comment: @diametralpitch It can't resolve it because I'm not linking to opengl32.dll at compile time; and **I actually don't want to**. I want to load it like LoadLibrary("opengl32.dll");

Comment: @diametralpitch But Glew actually needs those wgl functions; that's the problem ...

Comment: Opengl32.dll will not contains symbols beyond openGL 1.4.and probably you can't get better than glew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do what you are asking for, but you will have to go about it differently. Typically, when a shared library (or dll) is manually loaded at runtime, you will have to search, by symbol, for the functions you want to use and assign them to handles so you can call them.

What you are doing now will never compile because you are *explicitly* using symbol names that the linker cannot find. You have to replace all of these unresolved function calls with queries into your manually loaded shared library (opengl32.dll).

There's some good code you can use for reference in the [glfw project](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/58ceab5f1e9736a53c6812ad673460eb87d743b9/src/wgl_context.c). Take a look at both the `_glfwInitWGL` and `loadWGLExtensions` functions.

Comment: Wait, so glfw loads OpenGL dynamically ? Can you use glew with glfw ?

Comment: Apparently, it does. As for using glew with glfw, take a look at this [post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34102/can-i-use-glfw-and-glew-together-in-the-same-code).

Comment: Thank you :) Also(different subject), do you think it's a **good idea** to load OpenGL at runtime or should I just stick with compile time ?

Comment: You're welcome. I think it depends. After looking into glfw more it seems they do this for cross platform purposes. I prefer to link at compile time so I do not have to map all of the functions from the library.